# Расставить цифры по порядку при удалении объекта

Tags: jquery

Например удалим `player-2`, тогда останутся `player-1` и `player-3`

А нужно, чтобы при удалении, удаленное число замещало следующее. Чтобы при удалении `player-2` значения смещались в правильном порядке `player-1` и `player-2`

Как пройти циклом по `top--search--music--container--result` и раставить у дочек `player` правильное значение в `id` ?

```js
function remove(elem) {
  $('#' + elem).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top--search--music--container--result">
  <div class="player list--search--result--top" id="player-1">
    Track
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove('player-1');">Удалить</a>
  </div>
  <div class="player list--search--result--top" id="player-2">
    Track
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove('player-2');">Удалить</a>
  </div>
  <div class="player list--search--result--top" id="player-3">
    Track
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove('player-3');">Удалить</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться зачем?

Comment: Для работы с API Audio. Там в инициализации объекты по цифрам

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать порядковый номер элемента?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ `HTML:` 1,2,3,4,5 `API:` 1,2,3,4,5 при удалении 2 `HTML:` 1,3,4,5 `API:` 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="top--search--music--container--result">
  <div class="player list--search--result--top" id="player-1">
    Track
    <a href="#">Удалить</a>
  </div>
  ...

$(".player.list--search--result--top a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $all = $(this).closest(".top--search--music--container--result");
  $(this).closest(".player.list--search--result--top").remove();
  $all.find(".player.list--search--result--top").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("id", "player-" + (i + 1));
  });
});
```